# Screen flickering XPS 13 9310 second HDMI monitor

Tags: hdmi, xps

On my Dell XPS 13 9310, when I try to use a secondary HDMI monitor, through an usb-c HDMI adapter, I get these screen glithces, mostly when I click on the other screen, or when I try to scroll the browser on the main screen.

I tried with 2 different USB-C HDMI adapters just to make sure it wasn't a problem with the one I was using.

Ubuntu 20.04

Kernel: 5.10.0-1013-oem

Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaTBS.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be having the same issue. I think I can solve it (temporarily) by going to `displays` and in the settings disabling a screen, and then enabling both again. (As far as I can tell, hitting super+P doesn't work).
Xorg vs Wayland doesn't matter either.

update: It seems like it's enough to go to `displays`, select "Single display", wait a sec for it to disable built-in display, then hit "Revert settings" (or hit escape)

Comment: Please don't ask a question inside and answer. You can use comments to the original question for this purpose.